# How to use Google Mobile Vision in China?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-vision

I'm an Android developer and trying to implement Google Mobile Vision on Android device. However Google Mobile Vision depend on Google Play Service and it cannot be installed on most Chinese' mobile phone.
Is there any solution?
Thanks!

Comment: you can install the google play service apk from external sites.

https://www.google.com/search?q=apk+google+play+services+download.

Comment: You can use Face Api from azure/microsoft or https://www.kairos.com/face-recognition-api this or you can search for other options if you want

Comment: What functionality do you need? You can use the google vision REST API to get the data you need and have your server have vpn access to google cloud